# Creating TopoJson from shapefile with the Shape Escape (shpescape)

Tags: shapefile, topojson

Does [shpescape](http://www.shpescape.com/mix/) really work for creating TopoJson from shapefiles? I always get errors if uploading there zipped shapefiles.

The usual error message is:

```
OSError at /mix/uploads/296e3bc4a4073272c90904ba2e3f04c6/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: "shpescape", genius

Comment: Presumably your problem is due to the files being archived. Try unzipping and what if you use topojson instead?https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference

Comment: I just tried uploading a zip and received the same Django error - the site appears to be broken. You should let the maintainer know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I migrated the site to a new server and www-data didn't have access to npm, derp.  This should now be fixed.  Let me (ideally via feedback on the site) if you still have any issues w/topojson conversion.

Comment: Thanks a lot for creating shpescape.com Josh. Unfortunately, your website doesn't currently work. Do you have any other suggestions for converting shp files to fusion?